# Find the equation of the tangents given the gradient

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, circles

We're given that $x^2 + (y+2)^2 = 4$ and we're asked to find the equation of the lines where the gradient $=1$

Through implicit differentiation I got $x + (y+2)y'=0$
and if $y'=1$ then:

$y=-x-2$ is the relation where $y'=1$, which makes no sense to me.

I'm missing on something, so how do you go about finding the equations? (I know there're two.)

Comment: Consider re-doing your differentiation; if you differentiated with respect to $y$, then there's no way $\frac{d(x^{2})}{dy} = x$.

Comment: I divided the equation by $2$ (simplification).

Answer (score 1):

the equation $x^2 + (y+2)^2 = 4$ is the graph of the circle centered at $(0, -2)$ and of radius $2.$ tangents at the end of the diameter joining the points $(\sqrt 2, -2 - \sqrt 2), (-\sqrt 2, -2 + \sqrt 2)$ has the slope $1.$  they are given by $$x - y = \pm(2\sqrt 2 - 2).$$

Answer (score 0):

By implicit differentiation of $x^2+(y+2)^2=4$, we get
$$2x+2(y+2)y'=0$$
or
$$y'=\frac{-x}{y+2}$$
If we isolate $y$ in the equation of the circle, we have
$$y=\sqrt{4-x^2}-2$$
hence
$$y'=\frac{-x}{\sqrt{4-x^2}-2+2}$$
$$=\frac{-x}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}$$
Now letting $y'=1$ and solving for $x$ yields the two solutions $x=\pm \sqrt{2}$. These give the corresponding $y$-values of $\mp \sqrt{2}-2$.

Using point-slope form, the two equations are then
$$y+\sqrt{2}+2=x-\sqrt{2}$$
and $$y-\sqrt{2}+2=x+\sqrt{2}$$
or in more commonly-used slope-intercept form as
$$y=x-2\sqrt{2}-2$$
$$y=x+2\sqrt{2}-2$$

Comment: thanks ! so I guess the equation I got $y=-x-2$ is the equation joining the two points of tangency; am I right

Comment: Yes, it connects the two points.